# Find jQuery code that trigger then event in Web Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I joined a team to work on a project. Now that they use jQuery and a lot of the javascript file are external files instead of embedded.

When I clicked a button, which simply looks like:

```
<a class="button_cancel">Cancel</a>
```

It trigger an event which is defined in one javascript file.

Is there a way to locate the file (or even the exact line of the file) when the onclick is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some developer tools like the Firebug extension for Firefox (which I hope you already have). In Firebug's "Script" panel you can set "Break on next" (in the top left corner) which practically means, set a breakpoint in whichever line is executed next. Activate that. Then click the button. You should land in the executed file. If not step through the code a bit and you will get there.
The only annoying thing would be if there is some other JavaScript that is continuously running.

I believe the developer tools of Chrome, Safari and Opera provide similar features.

**EDIT:** Chrome has it too. Panel "Sources" in the top right, and it's called "Pause Script Execution".

Comment: hi, m.buettner, just tried your solution, Firebug didnt stop/pause and point to the line which should be triggered when i click the button. No idea why. But when i set the breakpoint at the exact line, it did paused there... so sad :(

Comment: hm, I tried it with Firebug and in Chrome with some JavaScript here on SO and it seems to work out quite nicely. You could try other browsers, but Firebug is usually pretty good with these things. Unfortunately, it's hard to tell where the issue in your case might be without seeing the page and JS code (which I assume you can't provide, can you?).

Comment: the debugger do stop at some lines, yet most of them are jquery-min.js which is not very helpful. Sorry i could not provide the code. I wonder if there's any way to just skip those jquery-min.js files. (I did enable the 'Pause on uncaught exception' in Chrome.)

Comment: I guess the JQuery code will do some dispatching before it delegates to the actually interesting function. So when the debugger breaks within jquery.min.js, just click a few times on "Step Into" until one of the functions in the interesting file is called. Also, what do you mean by "I did enable the Pause on uncaught exception"? Additionally? It shouldn't matter if you just activate "Pause Script  Execution" (or press F8 with the developer tools opened).

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Event 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) can provide you with this informations in a nice and easy to use way.

> Visual Event is an open source Javascript bookmarklet which provides
>   debugging information about events that have been attached to DOM
>   elements. Visual Event shows:
>
> - Which elements have events attached to them
> - The type of events attached to an element
> - The code that will be run with the event is triggered
> - The source file and line number for where the attached function was defined (Webkit browsers and Opera only)

[Demo](http://sprymedia.co.uk/VisualEvent/demo/)